# How can I make EaselJS' skew behave like canvas'?

Tags: html-canvas, transformation, easeljs

The skew property of a bitmap in EaselJS (given as angle) rotates the image such that it also flattens. I'd like to skew it without "squashing" it, as canvas does.

JSFiddles, to demonstrate:

[Canvas skew](http://jsfiddle.net/LBzUt/45/) | [EaselJS skew](http://jsfiddle.net/Bpz88/589/)

[image: canvas skew] [image: EaselJS skew]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, an unfortunate side effect of EaselJS being *too clever*. You can undo the cleverness by vertically scaling the resulting shape by the ratio of the desired height *h<sub>2</sub>* to the actual height *h<sub>1</sub>* that Easel calculated for you.

Here's a diagram to go help think about the [trigonometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry):

[image: The required trig]

I [modified your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bpz88/591/) to demonstrate how it might look in code. The important parts:

```
function degToRad(angle) {
    return angle * Math.PI / 180;
}

var angle = -35;
var shouldBeHeight = 80;
var isHeight = 80 * Math.abs(Math.cos(degToRad(angle)));
var heightRatio = shouldBeHeight / isHeight;

...

skewedShape.scaleY = heightRatio;
```

[image: How it looks now, rendered with EaselJS.]

Comment: Great, thanks. In the mean time I build some solution that uses the Matrix2D from easelJS and applied it to the canvas context. But it's good to have a way to solve it with easelJS.

Comment: Little visualization: http://jsfiddle.net/Bpz88/592/

Comment: @Tarion Does your method involve trig too? If not, it might be faster, which can be a big plus in render calls. (You could add it as another answer. It's OK to post answers to your own questions too.)

Comment: Ok it's not tested code I took it from my code that is still in progress and therefore somehow messy ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide and example how to use the easel Matrix2D to archive the skew:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.save();
var matrix = new createjs.Matrix2D();
var tile = new createjs.Bitmap('img/tile.png');
matrix.prepend(
            1, 0.5, // the 0.5 is the skewing
            0, 1,
            0, 0);
tile.draw(ctx);
ctx.restore();
```

But then you can not rely on the easel update mechanism but you must do this yourself whenever you need to render it.